# Electric power measurment

Tags: microcontroller, power, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I would like to be able to monitor the electrical power in my house because my distributor only provides me with the monthly maximums.

To do this I think I should measure the voltage and current of the line coming into my house and sample the two signals for further processing to obtain the power. I have seen that there are devices that measure the power, consumption or current and show it on a display, in my case I would like to be able to pass that information to a microprocessor (like an ESP32) and through the use of WiFi get the values on my personal computer.

I don't know if I can build this on my own with a current transformer and somehow measuring the voltage or I can buy one of these devices and set it up to work as I would like it to.

I know there are some that do all the WiFi stuff too but I would like to do it on my own.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Their examples of plenty of projects like this on the internet. Probably the easiest ones implementer cameras that read the meter and process information. Some meters might have the ability to read the information from the meter. Measuring high voltage is dangerous

Comment: See https://openenergymonitor.org/. A much simpler way is to log pulses from the utility's energy meter. Many blink an LED at a rate specified on the front of the meter. Put an optical sensor on that.

Comment: If the OP's "trust model" doesn't include the Power Meter Manufacturer, then some other method is required.

Comment: I was not aware that these devices being sold have an LED that flashes in proportion to consumption. This reduces the problem to just detecting the on and off of an LED. Thank you very much!

Comment: The “device” would be your power meter. Have you looked at it? Does it have a @flashing LED“?

Comment: "*... that these devices being sold ...*" I said use the utility company's energy meter. That's usually fitted somewhere the meter reading person can have access to read the meter.

Comment: I have not looked at it, and will check it out as soon as I have a moment as it is downstairs in the building and I need the keys. I understood that was what you were referring to but I have also seen on the internet that there are consumption meters that can be attached to the electrical panel at home (I think that's what they are for, if not please correct me). This way I can measure the pulses of any consumption meter that I am going to buy and install in my electrical panel.

Comment: Frankly, if you have to ask what the name of an electrical panel is, you're not ready to do this safely.  **You can kill yourself with this stuff**.  If you're going to go that route, get at least one book on DIY home electrical repair and read the safety rules carefully.  Better yet, if you're in some locale that has a community or junior college that teaches a basic DIY home electronics course -- take it.

Comment: depending on type of Your energy metering device, maybe a camera taking pictures of energy meter output could supply enough information for Your interest? (some helpful support towards this approach would be github.com/ayseceyda/analog-meter-reading-openCV, what is higher CPU level than Esp32, maybe converting hackaday.com/2021/02/07/an-esp-will-read-your-meter-for-you helps Your needs)